# Subkey registry with Powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

i want te get a list of all subkey registry with Powershell, i try to use this, but i have only the parent key "Peacy"

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Peacy
```

Any idea please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ItemProperty` will give you the *values* of a key. For enumerating the *subkeys* of a registry key you need to use `Get-ChildItem`.

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Peacy
```

Comment: Thanks for help :)